# Delphi xe2 encode/decode base 64

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, decode, encode, radix

Can someone provide me with an example of how to use `EncodeBase64` and `DecodeBase64` from library `Soap.EncdDecd`? I'm Using `Delphi xe2`

Comment: Did you try yourself? Did you read the docs? What are you finding hard?

Answer (score 7):

You are not specifying what kind of data are you trying to encode or decode. The `DecodeBase64` and `EncodeBase64` functions uses the `EncodeStream` and `DecodeStream` internally, in theory you can use these functions based on streams to encode or decode any type or data (after of use a stream to hold the data).

For encode/decode strings just use the `EncodeString` and `DecodeString` functions directly.

```
function  EncodeString(const Input: string): string;
function  DecodeString(const Input: string): string;
```

For streams use `EncodeStream` and `DecodeStream`

```
procedure EncodeStream(Input, Output: TStream);
procedure DecodeStream(Input, Output: TStream);
```

## Sample for EncodeBase64

```
function  DecodeBase64(const Input: AnsiString): TBytes;
function  EncodeBase64(const Input: Pointer; Size: Integer): AnsiString;
```

For example to encode a file and return a string using the `EncodeBase64` function you can try this (obviously you can use EncodeStream function directly too).

```
function EncodeFile(const FileName: string): AnsiString;
var
  LStream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  LStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    LStream.LoadFromFile(Filename);
    Result := EncodeBase64(LStream.Memory, LStream.Size);
  finally
    LStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Now to use the `DecodeBase64` function just pass an already encoded string and the function will return  a TBytes (array of bytes).

Comment: Hello, thanks for your example, but it doesn't work. When passing a string, there is an error message: "Cannot open the specific file (the path). The system cannot find the path specified". Who do I solve?

Comment: That is because the file doesn't exist. if you want encode a string just use the `EncodeString` function.